# how to make a sorting method in smalltalk

Tags: sorting, methods, smalltalk, squeak

I am trying to make a new sorting method in smalltalk. Anyone know how to change this sorting java code to squeak?

```
public static void SelectionSort ( int [ ] num )
{
     int i, j, first, temp;  
     for ( i = num.length - 1; i > 0; i - - )  
     {
          first = 0;   //initialize to subscript of first element
          for(j = 1; j <= i; j ++)   //locate smallest element between positions 1 and i.
          {
               if( num[j] < num[first] )         
                 first = j;
          }
          temp = num[first];   //swap smallest found with element in position i.
          num[first] = num[ i ];
          num[i] = temp; 
      }           
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a line by line translation. Row numbers are not part of the code.

```
 1. selectionSort: num
 2.    | first temp |
 3.    num size to: 1 by: -1 do: [:i |
 4.        first := 1. "initialize to subscript of first element"
 5.        1 to: i do: [:j |
 6.            "locate smallest element between positions 1 and i"
 7.            (num at: j) < (num at: first) ifTrue: [first := j]].
 8.        temp := num at: first. "swap smallest with element in position i"
 9.        num at: first put: (num at: i).
10.        num at: i put: temp]
```

**Remarks:**

1. No argument type declaration. No answer type.
2. Block temporaries `i` and `j` declared inside blocks (lines 3 and 5). In Smalltalk, indexed collections are 1 based.
3. `num.length()` -> `num size`. Decreasing `for` loop translates into `to:by:do:` message.
4. Assignment `=` becomes `:=` and `0` becomes `1` (see line remark 2 above.)
5. Increasing `for` loop translates into `to:do:` message.
6. Comments are enclosed between double quotes.
7. `[j]` translates into the `at: j` message. `if` translates into an `ifTrue:` message.
8. `temp` could have been declared in the first block: `do: [:i | | temp |...`.
9. `num[j] = temp` also becomes a message sending `at:put:`.
10. Idem 9. Note also that you could have used the cascade syntax for lines 9 and 10:

    ```
    num
        at: first put: (num at: i);
        at: i put: temp
    ```
11. No need to answer `num` because it's been modified by the method. See, however, the interesting discussion originated in Amos' answer: [Why shouldn't I store into literal arrays in Smalltalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29964346/4081336).

Comment: Thank you! this was extremely clear and helpful! i changed the way a bit but this explained the code step by step.

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer:**

You don't have to.

To sort an array, just send it the message `#asSortedCollection`. For instance, inspect this in a workspace:

```
#(7 2 8 5) asSortedCollection
```

**Long answer:**

Since I assume you want to see how you *would* implement the equivalent of your Java code in Smalltalk if you *really had to*, here's a relatively "literal translation" you can test in a workspace (tested in Pharo, should work in Squeak as well):

```
| someNumbers |
someNumbers := #(7 2 8 5) copy. "See comments below for an explanation."
someNumbers size to: 1 by: -1 do: [:eachOuterIndex |
    | indexOfSmallest swapValue |
    indexOfSmallest := 1.
    1 to: eachOuterIndex do: [:eachInnerIndex |
        (someNumbers at: eachInnerIndex) < (someNumbers at: indexOfSmallest)
            ifTrue: [ indexOfSmallest := eachInnerIndex ]
        ].
    swapValue := someNumbers at: indexOfSmallest.
    someNumbers at: indexOfSmallest put: (someNumbers at: eachOuterIndex).
    someNumbers at: eachOuterIndex put: swapValue.
    ].
^someNumbers
```

Clearly, there are a few changes from your version, such as using explicit naming, which is one of Smalltalk's hallmark conventions (in particular, `indexOfSmallest` should be clearer than `first`, which is misleading since it's not necessarily the first index), and decreasing the scope of the variables you called `first` and `temp`). See @Leandro's answer for a version that uses your own variable names if you have trouble with the "translation".

If the code were to live in a method, I would probably put it in the `SequenceableCollection` hierarchy (or maybe you'd want to add yours as a subclass in there if you want to override other behaviour), and the start of it could look something like this:

```
copySortedDescending
    "Answer a copy of the receiver, sorted in descending order."

    | copy |
    copy := self copy.
    copy size to: 1 by: -1 do: [:eachOuterIndex |
        "... and so on..."
        ].
    ^copy
```

Again, note that I'm deliberately changing the name, because I don't think `selectionSort` is a descriptive name of what the method does, and I wouldn't use a collection as an argument to a method living somewhere else - the knowledge of how to do the sorting belongs *on the collection itself*.

I'm sure you could come up with a better roll-your-own-answer very easily, though. For instance, you could try sending a `SequenceableCollection` instance the message `sort:` and pass a sort block as an argument, in which you could specify how you want your elements to be sorted.

Comment: Your code is mostly correct, but you should not store into a literal array (`#(...)`). Probably change the first line to `someNumbers := #(7 2 8 5) copy.`

Comment: @Tobias: Like I said, it's meant to be a "literal translation" of the OP's code. And it works as-is in Pharo... why not change values in it? I'm not iterating over the array, I'm iterating over indices.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But suppose you are writing this code in a method. you'd expect that every time you call it, that the first line is the same, but this isn't true after the first invocation. This is a bit complex so I made a community wiki entry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964345/why-shouldnt-i-store-into-literal-arrays-in-smalltalk/29964346#29964346

Comment: @Tobias: I appreciate the effort you went to in order to make your point, which is quite a tricky case - I upvoted both your question and your answer there. If this code _were_ to live in a method instead of just being a workspace example, obviously a literal array wouldn't be used in the first place - the array would be the argument, and the method would most likely "answer a sorted copy of the receiver". Happy to update the answer to include the `copy` though, thanks for pointing this out.