# Converting Ordered Collection to Literal Array

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I have an ordered collection that I would like to convert into a literal array. Below is the ordered collection and the desired result, respectively:

`an OrderedCollection(1 2 3)`
`#(1 2 3)`

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message `asArray` will create and `Array` from the `OrderedCollection`:

```
    anOrderedCollection asArray
```

and this is probably what you want.

However, given that you say that you want a *literal array* it might happen that you are looking for the string `'#(1 2 3)'` instead. In that case I would use:

```
    ^String streamContents: [:stream | aCollection asArray storeOn: stream]
```

where `aCollection` is your `OrderedCollection`.

In case you are not yet familiar with `streamContents:` this could be a good opportunity to learn it. What it does in this case is equivalent to:

```
    stream := '' writeStream.
    aCollection asArray storeOn: stream.
    ^stream contents
```

in the sense that it captures the pattern:

```
    stream := '' writeStream.
    <some code here>
    ^stream contents
```

which is fairly common in Smalltalk.

**UPDATE**

Maybe it would help if we clarify a little bit what do we mean *literal arrays* in Smalltalk. Consider the following two methods

```
method1
  ^Array with: 1 with: 2 with: 3

method2
  ^#(1 2 3)
```

Both methods answer with the same array, the one with entries `1`, `2` and `3`. However, the two implementations are different. In `method1` the array is created *dynamically* (i.e., at runtime). In `method2` the array is created *statically* (i.e., at compile time). In fact when you accept (and therefore compile) `method2` the array is created and saved into the method. In `method1`instead, there is no array and the result is created every time the method is invoked.

Therefore, you would only need to create the string `'#(1 2 3)'` (i.e., the literal representation of the array) if you were generating Smalltalk code dynamically.

Comment: I _hope_ `asArray` is everything you want - I may be curious to know why you'd want the string, otherwise :)

Comment: @mgarciaisaia Yes, I just realized what you say and have modified my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can not convert an existing object into a literal array. To get a literal array you'd have to write it using the literal array syntax in your source code.

However, I believe you just misunderstood what literal array means, and you are infact just looking for an array.

A literal array is just an array that (in Pharo and Squeak [1]) is created at compile time, that is, when you accept the method.

To turn an ordered collection into an array you use `asArray`.

Just inspect the results of

```
#(1 2 3).
(OrderedCollection with: 1 with: 2 with: 3) asArray.
```

You'll see that both are equal.

[1]: see here for an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29964346/1846474

Comment: @bert though i wonder, isn't the fact that a literal array is created at compile time an implementation detail? as http://stackoverflow.com/a/29964346/1846474 explains, what is significant is that we can not rely on literal arrays creating distinct objects or not.

Answer (score 1):

In Pharo 5.0 (a beta release) you can do:

```
    | oc ary |
oc := OrderedCollection new: 5.
oc addAll: #( 1 2 3 4 5).
Transcript show: oc; cr.
ary := oc asArray.
Transcript show: ary; cr.
```

The output on the transcript is:

```
an OrderedCollection(1 2 3 4 5)
#(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

the literalArray encoding is a kind of "poor man's" persistency encoding to get a representation, which can reconstruct the object from a compilable literal array. I.e. an Array of literals, which by using decodeAsLiteralArray reconstructs the object.

It is not a general mechanism, but was mainly invented to store UI specifications in a method (see UIBuilder).

Only a small subset of classes support this kind of encoding/decoding, and I am not sure if OrderedCollection does it in any dialect.
In the one I use (ST/X), it does not, and I get a doesNotUnderstand.

However, it would be relatively easy to add the required encoder/decoder and make it possible.

But, as I said, its intended use is for UIspecs, not as a general persistency (compiled-object persistency) mechanism. So I rather not recommend using it for such.